# MethodChaining on a LiveWire component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to create livewire component. When I init the component I want to pass some variables using methodChaingin.

For example:

```
class Test extends Component
{
    protected $model;
    protected $fields;
    protected $data;

    public function make(array $fields): static
    {
        $this->fields = $fields;
        return $this;
    }

    public function model($model){
        $this->model = $model;
        if (!$this->query) {
            $this->query($this->model::query());
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->ensureValidQuery();
        $this->data = $this->query->get();
        return view($this->view, get_object_vars($this));
    }

}
```

I would like to init this component like this:

```
$test = (new Text())->model($this->model)->make([
            __fields__
      ]);
```

The problem I have is that the render method in the component is called before the methodChain. So $model and $fields are null.

Is what I am trying possible with Livewire 3? If so, can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `mount` method instead of the `render` method to perform initialization tasks

```php
class Test extends Component
{
    protected $model;
    protected $fields;
    protected $data;

    public function make(array $fields): static
    {
        $this->fields = $fields;
        return $this;
    }

    public function model($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        if (!$this->query) {
            $this->query($this->model::query());
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        // Perform initialization here
        $this->model($this->model)->make($this->fields);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->ensureValidQuery();
        $this->data = $this->query->get();
        return view($this->view, get_object_vars($this));
    }
}
```

you can create and initialize your Test component

```php
$test = (new Test())->model($this->model)->make([
    // Your fields here
]);
```